# How do you assign more than one variable

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code:

```
*Panel="Terminator"
if Panel =='Terminator':
    import Terminator.py
else:
    import Sniffer.py*
```

Whenever I run it, it wont run `Sniffer.py` and I've tried

```
*    Panel="Terminator" and "Sniffer"
if Panel =='Terminator':
    import Terminator.py
if Panel =='Sniffer':
    import Sniffer.py*
```

but then it only opens `Sniffer.py` even when I type Terminator. I don't know a lot about python so any tips would help!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you possibly reply with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have '*' , are you planning to comment?. In that case use `#` before each line. or `""` before and after comment section.

Your code is working as intended.

```
def printme(Panel):    
    if Panel =='Terminator':
        print "import Terminator.py"
    else:
        print "import Sniffer.py"


>>> Panel="Terminator"
>>> printme(Panel)
import Terminator.py
>>> Panel="XYZ"
>>> printme(Panel)
import Sniffer.py
>>>
```